# My Print PDF Doesn't Show the Binded Data of the Original Window - C# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to print my window (Print Preview) using MVVM architecture. So far I was able to get the controls of the window into the print. But it doesn't show the data bindings.

This is my PrintPreview.xaml code

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <!--Main Grid-->
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height ="1.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height ="1.7*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height ="5*" MinHeight="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height ="7*" MinHeight="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height ="6*" MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height ="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#9dc6a7"/>

        <!--Patient Id block-->
        <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource StackpanelStyle}">
            <Label FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White">
                Patient ID :
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Path=PatientID}"/> 
        </StackPanel>

        <!--Date block-->
        <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource StackpanelStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Label FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White">
                Date :
            </Label>
            <Label Name="date_time" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentDate}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--Title block-->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="White">
            Patient Registration Information
        </TextBlock>

        <!--Sub grid 1-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="25,10,25,10">

            <!--User's image View and name-->
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Ellipse Width="150" Height="150">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="ImageViewer2" ImageSource="{Binding Path=PatientImageSource}"/>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyles}" Margin="0">Patient Name :</Label>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewName" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path = PatientName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <!--Sub grid 2-->
        <GroupBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,-35,25,0">
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleControl}">Patient Personal Information</TextBlock>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*" MaxHeight="80"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,5">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabelStyles}" >Address :</Label>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewANum"  Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path =  PatientAddress.Number}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewAStrt" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path =  PatientAddress.Street}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewACity" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path =  PatientAddress.City}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="50,5,10,10">
                    <Label  Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabelStyles}">Gender :</Label>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewGender" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path = PatientGender}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,5">
                    <Label  Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabelStyles}">Date of Birth :</Label>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewDob" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path = PatientDateOfBirth}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="50,5,10,5">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabelStyles}">Age :</Label>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewAge" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path = PatientAge}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <!--Sub grid 3-->
        <GroupBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,-25,25,0">
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleControl}">Patient Medical Information</TextBlock>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,5">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabelStyles}">Department :</Label>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewDepartment" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=PatientDepartment}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="50,5,10,0">
                    <Label  Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabelStyles}">Ward :</Label>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewWard" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=PatientWard}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,5,10,10">
                    <Label  Style="{StaticResource PreviewLabelStyles}">Doctor in Charge :</Label>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ViewDoc" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=PatientDotorcInCharge}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,7,26,0" Content="Print Content" Command="{Binding Path=PrintCommand}"/>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This is my PrintPreview ViewModel code,

```
class PrintPreviewViewModel
{
    #region Data Members
    private IWindowService m_windowService;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public PrintPreviewViewModel(PatientRecordDetailsModel patient)
    {
        string id = patient.PatientId;

        PatientID = id.PadRight(6).Substring(0, 6);
        PatientName = patient.PatientName;
        PatientAddress = patient.PatientAddress;
        PatientGender = patient.PatientGender;
        PatientDateOfBirth = patient.PatientDateOfBirth.ToShortDateString();
        PatientAge = patient.PatientAge;
        PatientImageSource = patient.PatientImageSource;
        PatientDepartment = patient.PatientDepartment;
        PatientWard = patient.PatientWard;
        PatientDotorcInCharge = patient.PatientDoctorInCharge;

        m_windowService = new WindowService();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string PatientID { get; set; }

    public string PatientName { get; set; }

    public PatientAddress PatientAddress { get; set; }

    public string PatientGender { get; set; }

    public string PatientDateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public int PatientAge { get; set; }

    public ImageSource PatientImageSource { get; set; }

    public string PatientDepartment { get; set; }

    public string PatientWard { get; set; }

    public string PatientDotorcInCharge { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region <PrintPreview> Members
    public string CurrentDate => m_windowService.GetCurrentDate();
    #endregion

    #region Properties : Commands
    public ICommand PrintCommand
    {
        get => new PatientRecordDetailsCommands(param => OnPrintCommandExecute(), param => OnPrintCommandCanExecute());
    }
    #endregion

    #region Handlers : Commands
    private void OnPrintCommandExecute()
    {
        m_windowService.PrintWindow();
    }

    private bool OnPrintCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }
    #endregion

}
}
```

As you can see I am opening the printPreview Window from another window through a service class. The patient object is being send through that. Also the implementation of print button command is also defined in the same service class. I used this approach to reduce the MVVM violations. 
This is my Service class

```
   class WindowService : IWindowService
   {

    public void CreateWindow(PatientRecordDetailsModel patient)
    {
        PrintPreview printPreview = new PrintPreview();
        printPreview.DataContext = new PrintPreviewViewModel(patient);
        printPreview.Show();
    }

    public string GetCurrentDate()
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        string date = dateTime.ToString("d");
        string time = dateTime.ToString("T");
        string Date_Time = date + " " + time;

        return Date_Time;
    }

    public void PrintWindow()
    {
        PrintPreview printPreview = new PrintPreview();
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();            
        PrintQueue ReceiptPrinter = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print To PDF");
        PrintCapabilities PC = ReceiptPrinter.GetPrintCapabilities();
        printDlg.PrintQueue = ReceiptPrinter;
        printPreview.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        Size PreGridSize = printPreview.DesiredSize;
        double Scale = Math.Min(PC.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / PreGridSize.Width, PC.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight / PreGridSize.Height);
        printPreview.LayoutTransform = new System.Windows.Media.ScaleTransform(Scale, Scale);
        Size PaperSize = new Size(PC.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, Math.Min(PC.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight, PreGridSize.Height));
        printPreview.Measure(PaperSize);
        Point ptGrid = new Point(PC.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, PC.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);
        printPreview.Arrange(new Rect(ptGrid, PaperSize));

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action(delegate () { printDlg.PrintVisual(printPreview.MainGrid, "PrintPreview"); }),
            DispatcherPriority.Send);

    }
}
```

I tried assigning the patient object to the datacontext inside the PrintWindow(), but it returns a null object.

[This is the original printPreview Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av7sU.png)

[This is how the print looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx9tG.png)

So I guess there should be a proper way of doing this.

Comment: Can you try changing your binding to remove the "Path=" part? E.g. {Binding PatientName}". It looks like your paths might be wrong.

Comment: Thank You ekke!, I tried it, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not assigning the DataContext inside your PrintWindow function.

let's take a look

```cs
    public void PrintWindow()
    {
```

here we create a new printpreview

```cs
        PrintPreview printPreview = new PrintPreview();
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();            
        PrintQueue ReceiptPrinter = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print To PDF");
        PrintCapabilities PC = ReceiptPrinter.GetPrintCapabilities();
        printDlg.PrintQueue = ReceiptPrinter;
        printPreview.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        Size PreGridSize = printPreview.DesiredSize;
        double Scale = Math.Min(PC.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / PreGridSize.Width, PC.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight / PreGridSize.Height);
        printPreview.LayoutTransform = new System.Windows.Media.ScaleTransform(Scale, Scale);
        Size PaperSize = new Size(PC.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, Math.Min(PC.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight, PreGridSize.Height));
        printPreview.Measure(PaperSize);
        Point ptGrid = new Point(PC.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, PC.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);
        printPreview.Arrange(new Rect(ptGrid, PaperSize));

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action(delegate () { printDlg.PrintVisual(printPreview.MainGrid, "PrintPreview"); }),
            DispatcherPriority.Send);

    }
```

as you can see you don't assign the datacontext to it. Indeed the createiwndow function in which you do assign the data context is not called at all.

you can see here the print command calls the PrintWindow function instead of createwindow.

```cs
    #region Properties : Commands
    public ICommand PrintCommand
    {
        get => new PatientRecordDetailsCommands(param => OnPrintCommandExecute(), param => OnPrintCommandCanExecute());
    }
    #endregion

    #region Handlers : Commands
    private void OnPrintCommandExecute()
    {
        m_windowService.PrintWindow();
    }

    private bool OnPrintCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: You mean that I should call CreateWindow function inside the PrintWindow()? But inside CreateWindow(), it's calling the printPreview.Show() method within, wouldn't it be an issue?

Comment: I mean you should assign the DataContext `printPreview.DataContext = new PrintPreviewViewModel(patient);` near the top of the PrintWindow function.

Comment: Hi ekke, It worked, after you mentioned this. What I did was, I sent the same patient object as a parameter to the PrintWindow(), which was used in the constructor. Then I assigned it to the DataContext inside the PrintWindow() implementation. Thank You Ekke!! :)